# Error from spin, gcc and cygwin

Tags: gcc, cygwin, 64-bit

I just installed Spin under Windows 7, and ran it from cygwin x86_64.
I ran the tests as suggested in the readme file until the third test.
`% spin -a loops.pml` 
`% cc -DNOREDUCE -o pan pan.c` 
`% ./pan`

it raised an error below:

`spin: error, the version of spin that generated this pan.c assumed a different w                                                                                                                ordsize (4 iso 8)`

By assuming the problem was bit compatibility between spin and gcc and cygwin, I changed the command to `cc -m32 -DNOREDUCE -o pan pan.c`, but the errors came when compiling.

`pan.c: In function ‘main’:
pan.c:8872:1: error: unrecognizable insn:
 }
 ^
(insn 201 200 202 28 (set (reg/f:SI 239)
        (symbol_ref:SI ("__ctype_ptr__") [flags 0x440] <var_decl 0x6ffffcec6e8 _                                                                                                                _ctype_ptr__>)) pan.c:8384 -1
     (nil))
pan.c:8872:1: internal compiler error: in extract_insn, at recog.c:2154`

Any suggestion?

Comment: Can't you just compile with `gcc -Wall -m32 ...` ?

Comment: How about building a 64-bit spin?

Comment: @PaulR, it resulted errors. Here actually what I did, following instruction from spin's readme file.
`spin -a loops.pml`
`cc -DNOREDUCE -o pan pan.c`
`./pan`

first two commands run well, but the last command raised an error.

Comment: OK - so what if you do: `spin -a loops.pml` `cc -m32 -DNOREDUCE -o pan pan.c`, like I suggested ? What *specific* errors do you get ?

Comment: @PaulR, here the error.
`pan.c: In function ‘main’:
pan.c:8872:1: error: unrecognizable insn:
 }
 ^
(insn 201 200 202 28 (set (reg/f:SI 239)
        (symbol_ref:SI ("__ctype_ptr__") [flags 0x440] <var_decl 0x6ffffcec6e8 __ctype_ptr__>)) pan.c:8384 -1
     (nil))
pan.c:8872:1: internal compiler error: in extract_insn, at recog.c:2154`

Comment: those errors are coming after the second command

Comment: OK - and what is around line 8872 in pan.c ? (BTW, edit your question to add the error messages and any further info - comments are not very readable or appropriate for code, error messages, etc.)

Comment: @PaulR, line 8872 is end of main function. `int main(int argc, char *argv[]){void to_compile(void); ... }`

Comment: I had the same issue. I guess spin does not support the compilation in Windows 64-bit.
I installed cygwin 32-bit instead of 64-bit on and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have downloaded spin.exe (x86) from the Spinroot website's Spin Precompiled executables.

1. install cygwin with bison (for yacc), gcc-core, gcc-g++, libgcc1, gdb, make
2. Download Spin sources, and compile a 64 bit spin.exe. Run make from within cygwin in the sources directory.
3. Move spin.exe to /usr/bin/spin.exe

You should be able to use spin as usual.